# Docker/Mysql loading in database dump - Container comes online before dump is fully loaded

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have a Docker-Compose setup the launches two containers. One is a custom Dockerfile image and the second is a container from the official MySql image from Docker Hub.

I have setup a Docker volume which links the MySQL container docker-entrypoint-initdb.d directory to my local machine. I have placed my database dump inside of this local directory.

When attempting to bring the container online with Docker-Compose, I've noticed that it can a little while for the import to fully complete, which means that the container hasn't actually finished loading for my purposes.

What is the best way of loading in this dump so that it is available at runtime? Do I need to run the dump during the build process rather that waiting for the container to load during runtime?

Comment: how big is your data that you are loading? Would it be sufficient to speed up the import process?

Comment: @danblack The import is only 127kb though it does have over 220 tables to create during this process

Comment: i've no idea why that's so slow.